# ffmpeg fails to load lensfun database

Tags: ffmpeg, video, lenses, distortion

I'm trying to correct lens distortion of a video.

I use below code that I took from here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Examples-132
(I just change the input and output file paths).

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf lensfun=make=Canon:model="Canon EOS 100D":lens_model="Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS STM":focal_length=18:aperture=8 -c:v h264 -b:v 8000k output.mov
```

But I get this error:

```
[Parsed_lensfun_0 @ 000002a85a0f7ac0] Failed to load lensfun database from default path
[AVFilterGraph @ 000002a8638fa880] Error initializing filters
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid data found when processing input
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

How can I resolve this issue?

I tried to give full path with db_path command as seen below:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf lensfun=make=Canon:model="Canon EOS 100D":lens_model="Canon EF-S 18-55mm f/3.5-5.6 IS STM":focal_length=18:aperture=8:db_path=E:\lensfun-master\data\db\slr-canon.xml -c:v h264 -b:v 8000k output.mov
```

And I get this similar error:

```
[Parsed_lensfun_0 @ 0000020b955cb7c0] Failed to load lensfun database from E path
[AVFilterGraph @ 0000020b94e2e9c0] Error initializing filters
Error reinitializing filters!
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid data found when processing input
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
Conversion failed!
```

Am I doing something wrong?